# Access Master page variables in child page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my master page file. I need to pass `strName`, `id`, `url`, `starttime`, etc. to my Child page. I know we can write this logic in our Child page, but, I would like to access this Master Page variable in my Child page only.

I cannot write this logic in each set/get method. While accessing these variable in the Child page, I am getting null values. basically here the master pageload calls after the child pageload calls over:

1. MASTER PAGE NAME:  MyMasterPage

```
     public partial class MyMasterPage: MasterPage
     {
         public string strName = string.Empty;
         public string id= string.Empty;
         public string url = string.Empty;
         public string startTime = string.Empty;
         public string endTime = string.Empty;
         public string remoteUrl = string.empty;
      
         public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            
            DataTable dtEventTable = DataAccessManager.GetEventInfo(Connection);
            
            if (dtEventTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                   strName = dtEventTable.Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString(); 
                   id = dtEventTable.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString(); 
                   url= dtEventTable.Rows[0]["URL"].ToString(); 
                   starttime = dtEventTable.Rows[0]["starttime"].ToString(); 
                   endtime = dtEventTable.Rows[0]["endtime"].ToString(); 
                   remotelive = dtEventTable.Rows[0]["remotelive"].ToString(); 
                   // assume that strName = "TCG",id=5, startime=20111001 etc.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

```
string name = ((MyMasterPage)this.Master).strName;
```

Read [Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)

Comment: I used the above approach, here i am getting null values in name variable. i debug the code. first child page_load calls then master page load calls.

Answer (score 5):

Found this by Ramesh T on https://forums.asp.net/post/5557778.aspx

> U better create a strongly typed reference to ur master page by adding
> a @ MasterType directive in ur content (aspx page) as shown below
>
> ```
> <%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage1.master"%>
> ```
>
> and access its members in your aspx page or code behind (aspx.cs) as
> below
>
> ```
> var test1Text = Master.test1;
> ```

This way you don't need to cast.

Answer (score 3):

This would work, as Muhammad Hasan and Pete suggested:

```
string name = ((MyMasterPage)this.Master).strName;
```

Or:

```
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage1.master"%>
var test1Text = Master.test1;
```

however, consider that code inside Page_Load event at master page, is executed **after** Page_Load in your content page.

So if you set the value of your variable in master page, and then try to get in content page, you will get null value.

you will find here more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

Comment: So it is better to move the code into Master page Init event?

Answer (score -2):

You can use Session[] object for reaching variables from another page.

Comment: Because `Session` has nothing to do with variables from another page.

Comment: can Session["variable"] = "abcdef";  be reached by another page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3963/discussion-between-gokturk-solmaz-and-john-saunders)

Comment: @Gokturk It can, Its ViewState or ControlState which cannot be used between mutiple pages.